# Number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5$ to $S_5$ and backwards

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have the following question on group theory:

> A. show that there are 745 different homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5$ to $S_5$
>
> B. How many different homomorphisms are from the group $S_5$ to $\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5$ ?

I have done a similar question about the number of homomorphisms from $D_4$ to $Q_8$, which uses the generating set of $D_4$. I assume that for A I need to do the same.

However, I don't think I have a generated set for $S_5$, and it appears I need to look at the kernel and image of the homomorphism.

I don't really have a strong grasp on group theory, so I could use some help with this. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2):

alex.jordan's answer has already addressed part (a), but I think there is an error in their solution to part (b).

Let $f \colon S_{5} \to \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ be an arbitrary homomorphism. Let $\sigma$ be an arbitrary transposition in $S_{5}$. Since $\sigma$ must have order $2$, we have
$$f(\sigma) + f(\sigma) = f(\sigma \cdot \sigma) = f(e) = (0, 0, 0),$$ hence $f(\sigma)$ has order dividing $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

However, since $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is a group of odd order, there are no elements of order 2, hence the only element with order dividing $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity.

Therefore, for any transposition $\sigma \in S_{5},$ $f$ must send $\sigma$ to the identity. However, we know that $S_{5}$ can be generated by transpositions, hence $f$ must send all of $S_{5}$ to the identity.

So, any homomorphism from $S_{5}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ must be trivial, hence there is only 1 such homomorphism.

Comment: I agree. The underlying fact is: the abelianization of the symmetric group is cyclic of order two, given by the signature $\epsilon : S_n \rightarrow \mathbb Z/2$. The means that for every morphism $f : S_n \rightarrow A$ to an abelian group $A$, there is a unique morphism $g : \mathbb Z/2 \rightarrow A$ such that $g\circ \epsilon = f$. So morphisms from $S_5$ to $(\mathbb Z/5)^3$ correspond (bijectively) to morphisms from $\mathbb Z/2$ to $(\mathbb Z/5)^3$.

Comment: I deleted my answer, thanks for straightening me out. You could add an answer to part A so there's a complete answer in one place now.

Comment: About part A, could there be a method that uses the kernel and image of a homomorphism?