Homomorphisms from $C_5\times C_5\times C_5$ to $S_5$
Questions:

Prove that there are exactly 745 homomorphisms from $C_5\times C_5\times C_5$ to $S_5$
Find all of the homomorphisms from $S_5$ to $C_5\times C_5\times C_5$

I have no idea how to start these questions. In question 1 i think i need to start by finding all of the normal sub-groups of $C_5\times C_5\times C_5$, but i have no idea how to do that.
Thanks for your help.

Note that every subgroup of $H=C_5\times C_5\times C_5$ is normal, as $H$ is abelian.

Thanks, but how can i find all of those subgroups? I think that there is another easier way to find the number of homomorphisms without the normal subgroups, is there a way?

For the second question: A homomorphism to a product is the same data as a homomorphism to each of the factors. So the question reduces to findining the homomorphisms from $S_5$ to $C_5$. But any homomorphism from $S_5$ to an abelian group must factor through the abelianization of $S_5$, which is $C_2$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4363882/491450

This has an answer only to question 2.

@Goaki. I added an answer to the first question in the linked post. (There was a deleted answer there that had answered the first part.)

This argument doesn't generalize well, but I guess that's to be expected.
First note that a homomorphism $C_5^3\to S_5$ is determined by the map on each of the three generators. Each generator must map to an element of order $1$ (the identity) or $5$. Each element of order $5$ in $S_5$ generates a Sylow $5$-subgroup. Sylow theory says that there are either $1$ or $6$ such Sylow $5$-subgroups. Either by exhibiting more than one of them, or by citing the known fact that $S_5$ is not solvable, we conclude that there are $6$ Sylow $5$-subgroups.
The image of any abelian group is abelian, and $5$ is the largest power of $5$ dividing $|S_5|=120$, so any map $C_5^3\to S_5$ factors through some map $C_5\to H\subset S_5$ for some subgroup $H\subset S_5$ isomorphic to $C_5$. Now we can easily count the number of maps in $\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z_5^3,\Bbb Z_5)$ as $125$. There are six possible choices for $H$, which gives $6\cdot 125=750$ homomorphisms. Finally, notice that we have double-counted the trivial map $5$ times.

can you explain more about the last part? I didnt understand where did you get the 125 from and where did you use the fact that the image of an abelian group is abelian.
